# Регулярные выражения в LINQ C# для разбиения строк

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, linq

Привет всем, не могу сделать разбиение строки на подстроки с помощью регулярных выражений, как это требуется. Нужно разбить строку на подстроки длины 2 или меньше, начиная с конца строки и занести подстроки в List. Есть код:

```
value = (from Match splitPart in Regex.Matches(number, @".{1," + 2 + "}") select Convert.ToInt32(splitPart.Value)).ToList();
```

но он делит с начала строки, например строку 12345 он разобьет как 12 34 5, а мне необходимо 1 23 45, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: В таком случае пометьте галочкой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена) Сделал так:

```
value = (from Match splitPart in Regex.Matches(unsig, @".{1," + 2 + "}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft) select Convert.ToInt32(splitPart.Value)).ToList();
```

если кому будет интересно.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы это не сделать через банальный цикл вместо регулярки?

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();

for (int i = str.Length-1; i>0; i-=2)
{
    string tmp;
    if (i!=1)
    {
        tmp = str.Substring(i-2,2);
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = str.Substring(0,1);
    }

    var tmpInt = Convert.ToInt32(tmp);
    lst.Add(tmpInt);
}
```

хоть кода и больше, скорее всего это решение будет читабельнее и быстрее. Ведь это простой перебор, а не серия регекс сравнений.

(код не проверял)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сначала проверить длину и если длина нечетное число, спереди добавить 0:

```
if (number.Length % 2 == 1) number = "0" + number;
```